# Seaborn tsplot: "Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape" even though index has no duplicates

Tags: seaborn

I want to make a picture much like the following:

[image]

I want to use seaborn to make the graphs look spiffy, and make it easier for myself to use facetgrids afterwards (I have ten different datasets I want to show in the same graph.)

The closest thing I have found in seaborn are the [tsplots](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/timeseries_from_dataframe.html).

I have data that looks like the following (five million rows):

```
   Bin_nb Sample           Type  Count
0     131   Exp1          Input      1
1      79   Exp2  Polymerase_II      1
2     100   Exp1          Input      2
3     173   Exp2          Input      3
4      40   Exp1          Input      1
```

The `Bin_nb` ranges from 0 to 200 and I'm pretending they represent time.

There are no duplicates in the index:

```
len(df.index.drop_duplicates()) # 5e6
```

Still I get the error `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`

When I try the command

```
sns.tsplot(data=df, time="Bin_nb", unit="Sample", value="Count", condition="Type")
```

Version info:

```
>>> sns.__version__
'0.6.0'
>>> pd.__version__
'0.17.1'
```

Comment: Upgraded to seaborn `0.7` and the error persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index that was duplicated was presumably the `Bin_nb Sample Type` tuple, of which there were several, each with its own `Count` value. Grouping and summing these fixed it!

```
rowdicts = []

for l, d in df.groupby("Bin_nb Sample Type".split()):
    d = {"Bin_nb": l[0], "Sample": l[1], "Type": l[2]}
    rowdicts.append(d)                               

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(rowdicts)
```

Now the data looks like:

```
     Bin_nb  Count Sample           Type
0         0  11118   Exp1          Input
1         0  10774   Exp1  Polymerase_II
2         0   8909   Exp2          Input
3         0  13704   Exp2  Polymerase_II
4         1  10388   Exp1          Input
5         1  11108   Exp1  Polymerase_II
```

and voilà plotting works!

```
sns.tsplot(data=df2, time="Bin_nb", unit="Sample", value="Count", condition="Type")
```

[image]